# Determine indentation of a line of code

Tags: strings, common-lisp

The following function determines the amount of indentation of a string. It returns two values. The first is an effective indentation where tabs are expanded such that their end aligns with 4 spaces steps. The second is just the amount of spaces and tabs before the first non-tab/space character.

`roundup` is a method that rounds the first argument to next higher multiple of the second argument. The rest is standard CL.

```
(defun indentation (line)
  (let ((spaces 0))
    (dotimes (index (length line) (values spaces index))
      (case (aref line index)
        (#\Space (incf spaces))
        (#\Tab (setf spaces (roundup (1+ spaces) 4)))
        (otherwise (return (values spaces index)))))))
```

I don't like having to state the return value twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `roundup` is something like
`(defun roundup (x y) (* (ceiling x y) y))`?

For the reason you stated I'd probably go with `loop` (or alternatives,
`iterate` comes to mind) instead of the `do...` family of macros, e.g.:

```
(defun indentation (line)
  (loop
    with spaces = 0
    for index below (length line)
    do (case (char line index)
         (#\Space (incf spaces))
         (#\Tab (setf spaces (roundup (1+ spaces) 4)))
         (T (loop-finish)))
    finally (return (values spaces index))))
```

- Depending on the choice of input you might want to use `char` for
  strings instead of `aref`.
- `otherwise` is pretty long, but of course it's somewhat of a personal
  choice - `t` is a bit shorter.

Comment: Your guess is correct.

I accept the answer, but will not use it for now. I do not like `loop` that much.

I was not aware of `loop-finish`. Seeing this used was helpful.